# Why are these sets equal (probability question)?

Tags: probability

> Two players A and B are competing at a trivia quiz game involving a
>   series of questions. On any individual question, the probabilities
>   that A and B give the correct answer are $\alpha$ and $\beta$
>   respectively, for all questions with outcomes for different questions
>   being independent. The game finishes when someone answers correctly.
>
> Compute the probability that A wins if: (a) A answers the first
>   question (b) B answers the first question

I understand most of the solution. In the solution, the author defines:

$A = \{A \ \text{answers the first question}\}$

$F = \{\text{Game ends after first question}\}$

$W = \{A \ \text{wins}\}$

At some point he goes on to write: $P(W | A \cap F^c) = P(W | A^c)$ and $P(W | A^c \cap F^c) = P(W | A)$ however I cannot get my head around why that is the case. Could anybody provide some intuition or explanation for this particular part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation $P(W | A \cap F^c) = P(W | A^c)$ states that the chance that $A$ wins if she goes first, and the game does not end after one turn, is the same as the chance that $A$ wins if she goes second. Note that if $A$ answers first, and she gets the answer *wrong*, then it is $B$'s turn, and the resulting situation is exactly the same as if $B$ had gone first. Hence, the chance that $A$ wins in either is the same.

The other equality expresses basically the same, but about $B$ going first.

Comment: Thank you very much! The bit I misunderstood was that they take it in turns to answer each question - I thought it was like one of those buzzer format game shows!